# Does mathematics fall within the domain of analytical philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, analytic-philosophy

Summary of the problem: I’m unsure if it is correct to think of mathematics as analytic philosophy in the domain of counting and am posting to gather perspectives.

Details and any research: make what you will of my construction “the domain of counting”, I’ve read a couple of books with “Introduction to Analytic Philosophy” in the title… not certain I understood very much, coming from way outside the field as I do and being new to it.

Description of  what I’ve tried: thinking, thinking and more thinking.  Discussing it with my colleagues who did mathematics at the highest level when they went though high school but majored in Engineering at University.  Searched the web for the phrase “mathematics analytical philosophy domain of counting” and posting to other related forums (hopefully this will not be tagged as a duplicate post, I’ve reworded it substantially)

Comment: Yes, it does, somewhat.  Re-reading it, i realise my question could more accurately be phrased “what is the relationship between counting and analytic philosophy?”.  Well, turns out Wittgenstein covered it already: https://www.newappsblog.com/2015/09/easy-as-1-2-3-wittgenstein-on-counting.html

Comment: Obviously not; mathematics is not phylosophy.

Comment: In a sense is the other way: with the **mathematician** [G.Frege](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/) started the modern development of *mathematical logic* and the modern approach to philosophy of mathematics and philosophy of language that was one of the main driving force for [Analytic Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analysis/#6). See at least M.Dummett's [Origins](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Origins_of_Analytical_Philosophy/lsSXQVBzJMoC) and M.Potter's [Rise](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Rise_of_Analytic_Philosophy_1879_193/Lti0DwAAQBAJ).